# How to code a simple torch light?

Tags: animation, particles

How would you code a simple "8 bit fire torch" (just one, nothing else to worry about on screen), without using any sprites?

For instance, how would you "animate" a torch that looks like this one:

[image: retro fire place]

Comment: any particular reason sprites are out of the question?

Comment: flip the image horizontally over and over. poof. animated.

Comment: @Jimmy, I think he's curious about writing a particle engine

Comment: @PlayDeezGames best flippin' answer I've read all week. +1

Comment: @JohnMcDonald I thought even [particle systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system) used sprites? I would say limiting yourself to not using sprites only means you will be drawing "sprites" at runtime

Comment: @PlayDeezGames great and simple answer, thanks man!

Comment: @PlayDeezGames http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/66103

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try the old school fire effect.

Let's say you store an 8-bit temperature value for each of your pixels. At each update:

1. Feed the bottom line with random "hot" pixels (e.g. 200-256).
2. For the others lines, all the way up:

   - Each pixel gets a new temperature from the pixel below
   - Times a random decay factor
3. Pick your pixel colors from an 8-bit palette with:

   - 256 = hot, white pixels
   - 0 = cold, black pixels
   - Shades of yellow, orange and red in between

See [this blog post](http://divergentcoder.com/random/new-old-school-fire/) for a Javascript implementation.
And [this](http://processing.org/learning/topics/firecube.html) for a Processing demo.

Some variants:

- Make the middle values hotter on the bottom line (e.g. with a Gauss curve)
- Get a mean of the pixels below instead of just one of them
- Play around with this pixel lookup, try to balance it with some "wind" factor, etc.

Comment: Great old-skool approach!

Comment: The "problem" with this approach is that it makes a smooth fire, and I want it to be like it's coming from the same "8bit flame" (pixelated). But thank you for your answer, I'll see what I can come up with :)

Comment: You could reduce the color space compared to the temperature space. E.g. 256 temperatures mapped to only 8 colors. Also, you could render 1 "real pixel" for an area of NxN "simulation pixels".

Comment: A good search keyword for approaches like this is "cellular automaton."